# Drools from clause not working

Tags: drools

The most basic use of from clause is not working, even when I know there are elements in the list and there is no conditions for the elements being extracted from that list, and I have other rules working properly.

Here is what happens, there are many variables in my problem, but I have simplified to this:

Having this two rules, the firstone is made to demostrate that `fixedShipmentValueData` list, has at least one element. However, the second rule isn't fired, even when the only different thing it does from the firstone, is to use the from clause and put a variable name.

```
rule "Print list value"
ruleflow-group "fixed-values"
no-loop
    when
        cParams: CustomerParameters(list: fixedShipmentValueData)
    then
        System.out.format("There are %s elements at fixedShipmentValue and fixed value is %s%n",list.size(), 
        ((ParameterValues)list.get(0)).getFixedShipmentValue());
end

rule "Do something with the list"
ruleflow-group "fixed-values"
no-loop
    when
        cParams: CustomerParameters(list: fixedShipmentValueData)
        ParameterValues($fixedShipmentValue: fixedShipmentValue) from list
    then
        System.out.format("fixed Shipment Value is %s%n", $fixedShipmentValue);
end
```

This looks so simple... I have expent enough time as to be out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the Java code for CustomerParameters, ParameterValues and the application part that creates, composes and inserts the fact(s) there's just one scenario I know that can reproduce the effect as you have told it. Consider this:

A `List<Base>` is field `list` in class X. There are subclasses `SubA` and `SubB` both extending `Base`. Create X, add objects of class `SubA` to `list`. A rule (like "Print list value") will show that the list is not empty.

However, a rule using a pattern such as

```
X( $list: list )
SubB() from $list
```

will never fire, since there are no SubB's in `Base.list`.

Comment: It may not cover your plight. But, if so, more info is required.

Comment: Thanks @laune for the quick answer.
You are right to say this is the only way one "can reproduce the effect", sadly, this is not the case. 
There are no subclases of 'ParameterValue', this is which makes this problem so weird.

I'm sure my aproach is correct because there are other rules using from clause with list of type 'ParamerterValue' and they work just fine.

Comment: If this is so, you'll have to provide a *complete* set of code, Java plus DRL that reproduces the issue. It shouldn't be too difficult in your case, but without that it's hopeless.

Comment: you highlighted _complete_ meaning no code snipets but a functional java app right?
if so, I'll try to share by git a simplified version of the problem, because is not actually that easy.

Comment: It must be possible to simplify it down to the essentials: a java class with that list, the classes you insert as list elements and the code building and inserting it. 100 lines, no more.